# App Closes with this error - requesting column name with table name

Tags: java, android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to use a ListAdapter to display the results of a Cursor.  According to my logs everything is returned the correct results until it gets to this point

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.cattle_layout,
            c,new String[]{"c.animal_id, c.eartag"},new int[]{R.id.TextView_cattleId,R.id.TextView_earTag});
```

At that point, the program throws an exception with the above mentioned message and it then names the two fields I want to display - from that point on it's next a java.lang.Exception and then references to the AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow

There has to be a problem with the 'new String[] creation", but I've searched and can't find anything.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Cursor Creation is

```
        String asColumnsToReturn[] ={
    "tbl_cattle._id",
    "tbl_cattle.animal_id",
    "tbl_cattle.eartag"};

    Cursor c = mDatabase.query(TABLE_CATTLE, asColumnsToReturn,"type_of_animal=?", new String[]{targetType},null, null, null, null);
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Record Count " + c.getCount() + " Columns: " + c.getColumnCount());
```

My Log gives me the correct count for the where clause, the correct data is in the records

Comment: Post your table creation statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
new String[] { "COLUMNNAME_ANIMAL_ID", "COLUMNNAME_EARTAG" }
```

where those two strings are just what they sound like. also you should really use static strings for column names. within your database define them once like :

```
public final static String COLUMNNAME_ANIMAL_ID = animalId; // where animalId is how the SQL column will be named.
```

and call that stuff from everywhere you need it with `DatabaseClass.COLUMNNAME_ANIMAL_ID`

in this example you would then use:

```
new String[] { DatabaseClass.COLUMNNAME_ANIMAL_ID, DatabaseClass.COLUMNNAME_EARTAG }
```

this way you a) can be sure you have no spelling errors in your SQL and b) can change column/table/DB names as quick as 1,2,3 - no matter where you used them.

Comment: yes i just used caps to illustrate that you should use the columnname  of the animalid from the cursor that you're getting the data from. are you sure you're using the right column names and the R.id's exist within your layout? also, have you looked if the cursor contains items? posting the hole debug stack would help.

Answer (score 2):

```
new String[]{"c.animal_id, c.eartag"}
```

to

```
new String[]{"c.animal_id", "c.eartag"}
```

(You had them as a single string.)

Also, it would be easier to read, debug, and maintain your code if you didn't try to cram everything into a single line.  "I did this in fewer lines that you" is not something that anyone really cares about, but "I can't remember what this is supposed to do and I can't figure it out from reading it" is a really big problem.

Comment: Tried and it failed and returned only the first string

Comment: You really should be more clear about your problems.  It fixed the exception that is thrown, right?  You didn't even post your code that uses the ListAdapter, how would we debug that?

Comment: Sorry about that, that's not intentional on my monitor it's a very wide screen so it doesn't seem to be too wide

Comment: I didn't put the code for the ListAdapter because it's failing before it gets to the adapter - and  no it didn't fix the exception

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering a similar problem and I think that the Cursor might not be correctly retrieve column names with a dot in the name that I have retrieved with a call to `rawQuery()`. E.g. `c.animalId` will not work but I bet if you changed the projection to `c_animalId` it would. It seems to be working for me.

Before I hit the error in the code I iterate over all the columns in the Cursor and I log a statement if a column equals the projection, which it does. Debugging and setting a breakpoint before the error I see all the columns exactly as I expect them in the Cursor. I know Android doesn't quote column names correctly at various other points in the code (which is ridiculous), and I think this problem is related to a similar issue.