# SimpleCursorAdapter can't find columns in database

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I found this question:
[App Closes with this error - requesting column name with table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050565/app-closes-with-this-error-requesting-column-name-with-table-name)
which is close to my problem, but not exactly, or at least I think I've addressed the solutions in that problem (i.e. creating an _id column and not using one string but two in my from array), and still no luck.
Also found this question: [ContactsContract query column 'display_name' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634878/contactscontract-query-column-display-name-does-not-exist)
which is even closer to my problem, but I didn't think it applied. Maybe I don't understand the answer in that one.

Here's the function where I'm having problems.

```
private void fillData() {
    String[] from = new String[] { EventTable.COLUMN_KIDNAME, 
        EventTable.COLUMN_KIDRUNNINGTOTAL};
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        null, from, to, 0);         
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In the above where I set the third argument (cursor) to null, I also tried to create a cursor like the below and got the same error.

```
String[] eventProjection = { EventTable.COLUMN_ID, EventTable.COLUMN_TASKITEM,     
    EventTable.COLUMN_KIDNAME,
    EventTable.COLUMN_KIDRUNNINGTOTAL, EventTable.COLUMN_DATEDONE };

Uri fillUri = Uri.parse(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI + "/");
Cursor someCursor = getContentResolver().query(fillUri, eventProjection, null, null, null);
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
    someCursor, from, to, 0);
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with this function, but it's part of the error messages

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data);
}
```

I query the database in another activity without any problems, so I'm pretty confident the columns actually do exist int the table. Here's the database creation blocks:

```
public static final String TABLE_EVENT = "event";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TASKITEM ="taskItem";
public static final String COLUMN_KIDNAME = "kidName";
public static final String COLUMN_KIDRUNNINGTOTAL = "kidRunningTotal";
public static final String COLUMN_DATEDONE = "dateDone";

// Database creation SQL statement
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table " 
    + TABLE_EVENT
    + "(" 
    + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
    + COLUMN_TASKITEM + " text not null, " 
    + COLUMN_KIDNAME + " text not null,"
    + COLUMN_KIDRUNNINGTOTAL + " float not null,"
    + COLUMN_DATEDONE  + " datetime default current_timestamp"
    + ");";

public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
}
```

The app throws this error as soon as the main activity starts, which of course kills the app. When I replace EventTable.COLUMN_ID for EventTable.COLUMN_KIDRUNNINGTOTAL in the from string array assignment above, it works, but of course it returns the record ID column, and I want the COLUMN_KIDRUNNINGTOTAL column.

I tried the code with just one column, EventTable.COLUMN_KIDNAME, of course amending the from and to arrays and the layout, and it works fine. I've tried all the other columns singly and none of them worked, except for COLUMN_ID of course. I'm puzzled why one column works but the rest do not.

Here's the full stack trace error. Sorry if this is ugly, I couldn't figure out how to post the logs right.

```
01-03 14:33:41.580: D/AndroidRuntime(21838): Shutting down VM
01-03 14:33:41.580: W/dalvikvm(21838): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415c2930)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'kidRunningTotal' does not exist
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:78)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:333)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at  android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:345)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at net.example.OverviewActivity.onLoadFinished(OverviewActivity.java:152)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at net.example.OverviewActivity.onLoadFinished(OverviewActivity.java:1)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:483)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:451)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:143)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:113)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:43)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:254)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:91)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-03 14:33:41.666: E/AndroidRuntime(21838):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 14:33:44.463: I/Process(21838): Sending signal. PID: 21838 SIG: 9
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: could you change the "float" data type to real  or integer and then try once again ?? ensuring that u uninstall the app and then install it again

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but changing to int didn't have any effect.